# Neo4j Cypher, redundant matches and performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on Cypher query builder.

Right now I faced the situation where the builder produces the following redundant matches:

```
MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.id = 10 AND n.value1 = 123 MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.id = 10 AND n.value2 = 777
```

As you can see we have there two redundant matches:

```
MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.id = 10
```

Do I need to rewrite my builder to simplify this query to something like that:

```
MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.id = 10 AND n.value1 = 123 AND n.value2 = 777
```

or the Cypher and Neo4j itself are smart enough to optimize such queries internally and these redundant matches will not affect the performance?

Comment: Why not get the execution plan and find out? https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/

Comment: or MATCH (n:Node {id:0, value1:123, value2:777})

Comment: I would recommend generating succinct Cypher queries if that is not too hard. Even if profiling shows that your currently used Cypher planner would not generate multiple matches, that does not guarantee that a future planner would do the same. Also, succinct Cypher would make your debugging easier and reduce the amount of time needed to transmit the query and to generate the plan.

Comment: thanks, I'll follow this recommendation!